# Java regular expressions for Zip, telephone, email and date

Tags: java, regex

I have four regular expressions in Java that match a:

```
Zip code : ([0-9]*)([0-9\\-])([0-9]+)
telephone: ([0-9]+)([\\-]?)([0-9]+)([\\-]?)([0-9]+)
email    : ([a-z0-9_\\.-]+)@([\\da-z\\.-]+)([\\da-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)
date     : ((19|20)\\d\\d)[/-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[/-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
and ((19|20)\\d\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

They are working as I expected. But if I apply a max length and min length for whole they no longer match.

For example:

```
zip  : ([0-9]*)([0-9\\-])([0-9]+).{2,10}
email:  ([0-9]+)([\\-]?)([0-9]+)([\\-]?)([0-9]+).{64}
```

I want to add min and max length for all of these regular expressions.

Comment: Did you mean Javascript or Java?

Comment: Now in java than I will implement same in javascript

Comment: @shahinbd Any luck with the regexes?

Comment: Thanks Jerry. They are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a look-ahead anchored to start, eg

```
^(?=.{2,10}$)([0-9]*)([0-9\\-])([0-9]+)
```

The expression `^(?=.{2,10}$)` says "no matter what other regex follows, the whole input must be 2-10 characters long"

Answer (score 0):

It'll be a bit difficult to apply the max length to those regexes without having to rewrite almost everything. Your best bet might be to use a positive lookahead:

```
zip : ^(?=.{2,10}$)([0-9]*)([0-9\\-])([0-9]+)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will make sure the zip is between 2 to 10 chars

```
email :  ^(?=.{64}$)([0-9]+)([\\-]?)([0-9]+)([\\-]?)([0-9]+)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will make sure the email is 64 chars long. Change to `^(?=.{1,64}$)` for 1 to 64 chars.